# Topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ versus $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

What are the topology of these two noncompact manifolds $M_1=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ versus $M_2=\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$, their differences? The inner product of the vectors for $M_1$ relies on the Euclidean metric:
$$
g_{ab}=\delta_{ab}, \quad a,b \in 1,2,...,n+1.
$$
The inner product of the vectors for $M_2$ relies on the (pseudo) Minkowski metric:
$$
g_{1,1}=-1, \quad g_{ab}=+\delta_{mn}, \quad a,b \in 2,...,n+1.
$$
All off diagonal components are zeros.

1. Homotopy group:

- I believe both have the $\pi_0(M_1)=\pi_0(M_2)=0$. So only one piece.
- I believe both have the $\pi_1(M_1)=\pi_1(M_2)=0$. So only contractible cycles.
- how about higher homotopy groups $\pi_k(M_1)$, or $\pi_k(M_2)$?

2. Homology groups:

- how about higher homotopy groups $H_k(M_1)$, or $H_k(M_2)$?

3. Are there some topology ways to distinguish $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ versus $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$? What are those topological differences between the $M_1=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ versus $M_2=\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$?

Comment: Well, what is the underlying topological space of $\mathbb R^{n,1}$?

Comment: How are using the pseudo-metric to define a topology on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: The topology of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold is not determined by metric; it must be specified beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer: They're the same thing.**

---

Just echoing what has alredy been mentioned in the comments. A smooth manifold is a triple of information $(M,\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{A})$, where $M$ is a set, $\mathcal{T}$ is a (Hausdorff, second countable) topology for $M$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal smooth atlas. A pseudo-Riemannian manifold is then a quadruple of information $(M,\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{A}, g)$, where $g$ is a smooth $(0,2)$ tensor field on $M$ which is pointwise a symmetric, bilinear, non-degenerate functional. As you can see, the definition of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ comes BEFORE we even talk about the tensor field $g$. Said differently, changing $g$ DOES NOT affect the topology.

When we speak of "the Riemannian manifold $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$", we mean

- We consider the set $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, together with the "usual" topology $\mathcal{T}_{n+1}$ (i.e $U\in\mathcal{T}_{n+1}$ if and only if for each $p\in U$ there is an $r>0$ such that for all $q\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(q^i-p^i)^2}<r$, we have $q\in U$). Then we consider the unique maximal atlas which contains the identity chart $(\Bbb{R}^{n+1},\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^{n+1}})$. The Riemannian structure is obtained by considering the tensor field $\delta:=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(dx^i)\otimes (dx^i)$.

When we speak of "the Lorentzian manifold $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}$", we mean

- We consider the **same** set $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, the **same** topology $\mathcal{T}_{n+1}$, the **same** maximal smooth atlas containing the identity chart. The only difference is we're considering a different 'geometry', i.e given by the tensor field $\eta:=-(dx^1)\otimes (dx^1)+\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(dx^i)\otimes (dx^i)$.

But like I've already said, the tensor field you choose to consider, $\delta$ vs $\eta$ makes no difference at all to the topology.

Comment: thanks - I voted +1. let me get back

Comment: But I am confused. For example, I thought SO(d) has only a single connected piece. But the SO(d-1,1) has two connected pieces. Aren't they differed only by the metrics?

Comment: The above is to response "As you can see, the definition of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ comes BEFORE we even talk about the tensor field . Said differently, changing  DOES NOT affect the topology."  Then we see the topology of SO(d) and SO(d-1,1) are different!?

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS $\text{SO}(\text{stuff})$ is a certain subgroup of invertible endomorphisms of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, which again has nothing to do with the topology of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Why are you mixing up the topology of $\text{SO}(\text{stuff})$ with that of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: I am only concerning the two kinds of metrics signatures shown in my first two equations. Same issues for ℝ+1 versus ℝ,1, or SO(d) and SO(d-1,1)

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS I'm going to repeat one last time: $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}$ are the same set. As a set, they're defined as all ordered $(n+1)$-tuples of real numbers. SO(n+1) is the set of all linear maps $f:\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\to\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, such that it "preserves" the Euclidean inner product. SO(1,n) is the set of all linear maps $f:\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\to\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that it "preserves" the Lorentzian inner product. As sets and topological spaces, $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, SO(n+1) and SO(1,n) are completely different things. So I'm not sure why you're mixing them up.

Comment: it's like you're mixing up apples and peanut butter: completely unrelated and different things. I suggest you look up the definitions of these three objects $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, SO(n+1), SO(1,n) and convince yourself that they really are COMPLETELY different sets of objects, and thus there should be no reason to expect any similarity between their topologies. Also, by definition, $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}=\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ as a set and also as a topological space. Note that $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}\neq$ SO(1,n). They're completely different objects

Comment: If this still doesn't sink in. I suggest you stop using the notation $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}$. Instead, always write out the following monstrosity "Consider the set $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, with its usual topology and usual maximal smooth atlas. For the rest of the discussion, let us fix the tensor field $\eta=-(dx^1)\otimes (dx^1)+\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(dx^i)\otimes (dx^i)$". This should emphasize to you that $\Bbb{R}^{n,1}$ is nothing but a short notation which summarizes the 2 sentences I quoted above.